# Offset two divs from the center, inside a container div

Tags: css, html

I want to put a banner across the top of a webpage. The first way I tried I couldn't get the two divs to position each other properly. They weren't offsetting from the middle (using the same technique that a single, static div would) and one was below the other.

Here's the code
http://jsfiddle.net/AndyMP/wFutk

I then managed to do it a different, easier way
http://jsfiddle.net/AndyMP/TJjwp/1/

But of course it is bugging me that I couldn't get the first method to work. Any guidance would be appreciated, in particular how to offset correctly from the middle of the container div.

(**Edit: I should add that I did this in IE9 and you might need to adjust the size of the preview pane in jsfiddle to see it all)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One was below the other because you were using `position: relative` ([Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#relative-positioning)).  In that mode, the divs are first layed out using normal flow and then offset.  So `top: 2px` was offsetting each one 2 pixels below where it would normally be.

Use `position: absolute` on the two inner divs instead.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `float` property seems to be a really good idea here

http://jsfiddle.net/wFutk/1/